# How to transition from plane to cylinder

Tags: modeling

I'm trying to figure out the best way to have a cylinder that splits at its midpoint and and smoothly transitions/flattens out into a plane. So far I've kind of figured out one way of doing this by having a plane and cylinder joined together as a single mesh and connecting the edges of the plane to the edges of the cylinder. Turned out like this: [image: pic]  Thought's and suggestions appreciated!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[image: final]

### Steps:

1. Enable **LoopTools** add-on.
2. Create **Circle** with chosen vertices count. Mine is 16.
3. Go to **Edit Mode** rotate **Circle** 90 degrees (X or Y axis).
4. Select top most vertex on the **Circle** and hit <kbd>V</kbd> to **Rip** selected vertex to two vertices. Now **Circle** has 17 vertices.
5. Create line with 17 vertices. I've done it by adding a **Plane**, deleted two vertices and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> > 15 (15 cuts + 2 verts = 17).
6. Level line with **Circle** bottom. I've used snapping. And also scale it a bit.

[image: step5]

6. **Select All** <kbd>A</kbd> than <kbd>W</kbd> ***> LoopTools > Bridge*** and set number of **Segments** and **Strength** of this bridge.
7. Extrude line to have a plane and extrude circle to have a tube.

[image: gif]